# Why Druid cluster crashed for indexing task?

Tags: druid

Can anyone tell me what & why cause my Druid cluster crashed during run indexing service?

> 2018-06-15T11:20:30,005 ERROR [forking-task-runner-1]
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList - RuntimeException
>   while executing runnable
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4@5d6c7c87 with executor
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService@13d11704
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskManager$$Lambda$39/1941452734@3eb73694
>   rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@75b7801a[Terminated, pool size
>   = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 25]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskManager.submitNoticeToExec(WorkerTaskManager.java:179)
>   ~[druid-indexing-service-0.12.0-iap10.jar:0.12.0-iap10]   at
>   io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskManager.access$000(WorkerTaskManager.java:77)
>   ~[druid-indexing-service-0.12.0-iap10.jar:0.12.0-iap10]   at
>   io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskManager$2.onSuccess(WorkerTaskManager.java:243)
>   ~[druid-indexing-service-0.12.0-iap10.jar:0.12.0-iap10]   at
>   io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskManager$2.onSuccess(WorkerTaskManager.java:239)
>   ~[druid-indexing-service-0.12.0-iap10.jar:0.12.0-iap10]   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1181)
>   ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>   ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>   [guava-16.0.1.jar:?]  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>   [guava-16.0.1.jar:?]  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask.done(ListenableFutureTask.java:91)
>   [guava-16.0.1.jar:?]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:384)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:233) [?:1.8.0_171]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]

Comment: Look for more logs.